# Django access to model Properties Dynamically

Tags: django, django-models

I'm very new to Django so this question might be very basic.

I have a model called `UserScores`, which contains 16 different score properties, each representing a user score based on the game he/she has played.

when a user plays a game and finish it, the score he gets in that game should be added to the related property in his/her UserScores object. so the code looks like this:

```
if game_name == "game_1":
  self.game1_score += score
elif game_name == "game_2":
  self.game2_score += score
...
```

in php I used to run a code like this:

```
obj.{game_name} += score
```

so no matter what the game name was, the correct property was edited,

Now my question is that,

> Is there a dynamic way to access properties on a Django model objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use getattr/setattr to achieve what you want. For example, to set the field value:

```
old_value = getattr(obj, field_name)
setattr(obj, field_name, old_value + score)
```

Comment: Thanks it works, But I'm not allowed to assign bounty in less than 21 hours, so I will assign it tomorrow

Comment: Hi Alireza, glad I could help.